# sphinx search doesn't show result when select custom fields

Tags: sphinx

Im using sphinx for searching the database, but i'm having an problem when i select custom fields in the query. Can anybody help me?

For ex. When i test it with this query:

`SELECT FROM events JOIN events_gategory ON events.category_id = events_gategory.id`

it works correctly

but when i use this query:

`SELECT events.name FROM events JOIN events_gategory ON events.category_id = events_gategory.id`

sphinx doesn't show any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this query, in 'sql_query' in your 'source'?

If so, it will need a unique id as the first column in the list of columns.

Comment: I'm using it with select * and it's ok, but i don't understand what's the problem when custom fields are selected?

Comment: Well you need at least a unique id, and one text field. So sql_query = SELECT id, name FROM ...

Comment: Yes this was the problem. I was selecting all the needed fileds from both tables (events and events_gategory) but i had forgoten to select events.id.

THANX 4 the help